# Inserir registro many-to-many - EF Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

**Problema:**
Estouro de erro ao tentar criar registro na tabela com relacionamentos.

**Erro**

*quando passo os membros virtuais com a instância do seus tipos:*
O banco devolve dizendo que não consegue encontrar a chave 00000000 na tabela teamId.

*quando passo os membros virtuais como null:*
o banco devolve dizendo não conseguir encontrar chave com valor null.

**Dúvida**
 Como inserir o registro sem precisar fazer o get do objeto completo de user e do objeto completo de team ? Sem interferir no **.include** utilizado quando resgato os registro da **UserTeam**.

Model **UserTeam** responsável pelo relacionamento "muitos para muitos" entre **ApplicationUser** ("Table: AspNetUSers") e **Team**.

```cs
    public class UserTeam : Entity
    {
        // Empty constructor for EF
        public UserTeam() { }

        public string UserId { get; set; }
        public virtual ApplicationUser Member { get; set; }
        public Guid TeamId { get; set; }
        public virtual Team Team { get; set; }
        public string RoleId { get; set; }
        public virtual ApplicationRole Role { get; set; }
    }
```

Método responsável pela criação de um novo registro na tabela **UserTeam**

```cs
    public async Task<(bool succeeded, string message, UserTeam data)> AddUserInTeam(UserTeam teamUserRole){

                await _context.UserTeam.AddAsync(teamUserRole);
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                return (true, "", teamUserRole);
            }
```

O parâmetro **teamUserRole** usado no método acima foi criado na service da seguinte forma

```
        // assinatura do método ...
        _teamRepository.AddUserInTeam(new UserTeam { TeamId = teamId, UserId = user.Id, RoleId = "9083caa8-f847-4f5b-ae7f-b5d60c2059a1" })

       // fechamento do método ...
```